# Type of singulariy of $\tan(1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

First list up two statements:

(I) Limit point of $\textbf{zeros}$ of a non-zero analytic function is $\textbf{isolated}$ essential singularity.

(II) Limit point of $\textbf{poles}$ of a fuction is $\textbf{non-isolated}$ essential singularity.

Now I have to check the singularity of $f(z)=\tan (1/z)$ at $z=0$.

Here, $\displaystyle f(z)=\tan(1/z)=\frac{\sin(1/z)}{\cos(1/z)}$.

Then zeros of $f$ are given by $\sin(1/z)=0$ which implies $z=1/n\pi$, which has limit point $0$. So $z=0$ is $\textbf{isolated}$ essential singularity of $f$ (by (I)).

Again, poles of $f$ are given by $\cos(1/z)=0$ which implies $z=2/(2n+1)\pi$ , which has limit point $0$. So, $z=0$ is $\textbf{non-isolated}$ essential singularity of $f$ (by (II)).

Which one is correct here ? I am confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct but one of your assumptions is wrong. Statement (I) is not valid in general. Any limit point of zeros of a non-zero analytic function must be an essential singularity, but it may or may not be isolated. You've already provided a counterexample!

Here's another counterexample that might be simpler: Let $f(z) = e^z$, $T(z) = \frac{z-1}{z-e}$, and $g = T \circ f$. Let $A = \{2 \pi i k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $B = \{1 + 2 \pi i k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. For all $a \in A$ we have $g(a) = T(f(a)) = T(1) = 0$, and for all $b \in B$ we have $g(b) = T(f(b)) = T(e) = \infty$. $\infty$ is a limit point of both $A$ and $B$, so $\infty$ is a limit point of zeros of $g$ AND a limit point of poles of $g$. Once again this would create a contradiction if both of your statements (I) and (II) were valid.